# Why is this command to give with enchantments not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to give myself a dead bush with OP enchants in 1.16.5, but it's not working.

```
give @a minecraft:dead_bush{Enchantements:[{id:sharpness,lvl:3000},{id:knockback,lvl:3000},{id:sweeping_edge,lvl:3000},{id:bane_of_arthropods,lvl:3000},{id:fire_aspect,lvl:3000},{id:looting,lvl:3000},{id:smite,lvl:3000}],Unbreakable:1}
```

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled `Enchantments` as `Enchantements`.